# Using Javascript/PHP/HTML/SQL to display results and "more results", but not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I have a site which displays information on cars. "Information" (Make, Model etc) and I currently have a seperate button "Show more information" (Mileage, BHP etc). All this is currently doing is, getting the information from the database then when I click show more information it hides the first tab and displays the second tab only.

Its a simple toggle_visibility function which just hides list 1 when list 2 is clicked. However, now, I want to have the "show more information" button next to each car. EG. Porsche Carrera - "Show more information" which then dynamically on the same page brings up a box below showing the mileage and so on. Then when I click on a different one, it to hide the first one and show that.

Code currently:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from Cars";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $display = "<p>";
        $display.= $result["makeID"] . "&nbsp;";
        $display.= $result["modelID"] . "&nbsp;";
        $display.= "<a href = '#'>Show more information</a>";
        $display.= "</p>";
        echo ($display);
    }
?>
```

The ahref # is:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list2');">
    </a>
    <div id="list2" class="alist" style="display:none;">

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from Cars";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $display = "<p>";
        $display.=$result["makeID"];
        $display.= $result["modelID"];
        $display.= "</p>";
        echo ($display);
    }
?>
```

Any help?

*EDIT* -Includes JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
        for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
            thelist[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: do you have any js file or code?

Comment: Yes I do have JS code in the same page..

Comment: add that code also, then only i can help you.

Comment: add that script just before body close.

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant but I tried adding it to the bottom before body close but it made no difference...